# AngularJS - Limit increment and decrement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two buttons, one is for increment and other for decrement my scope.

I want : Min. number = 0 and Max. number = 50.

I've try this :

```
myApp.controller('StepCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $state, $stateParams) {


    $scope.event = {
      priceid: 0,
    }

   if ($scope.event.priceid === 0) {

    console.log("This is 0")

    $scope.nextPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid += 5;
    }

    $scope.previousPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid = 0;
    }     

    } else if ($scope.event.priceid === 50) {

    console.log("This is 50")

    $scope.nextPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid = 50;
    }

    $scope.previousPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid -= 5;
    }

    } else {

    console.log("This is into 0 and 50")

    $scope.nextPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid += 5;
    }

    $scope.previousPrice = function() {
      $scope.event.priceid -= 5;
    }

    }

})
```

But, I can have value like -40 or 95, I think my "If" and "Else" are ignored.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks for reply. :)

Comment: You will need to put the full controller in. As your code stands, it will only run ONCE. It will only run when your controller is instantiated and NEVER AGAIN. This code isnt put into a function to run on button click. Please paste your full controller in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to see your full controller to get the full picture. But I believe the problem is that your expressions are being evaluated once at startup instead of in real-time.

My solution would be to replace your if-else statement with this.

```
$scope.event = {
  priceid: 0,
}

$scope.nextPrice = function() {
  if($scope.event.priceid < 50)
    $scope.event.priceid += 5;
}

$scope.previousPrice = function() {
  if($scope.event.priceid > 0)
    $scope.event.priceid -= 5;
}
```

This way your condition will be evaluated every time you call $scope.previousPrice() or $scope.nextPrice() instead of those methods just being assigned to at runtime.

Comment: This one works until you will decide change iterator from 5 to 6 for example. Than your condition will fail and produce 54. Cause 6*8 less then 50, and another one addition will result 54.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to explore this solution:

```js
var event = {
  priceid: 0,
  priceIterator: 45,
  nextPrice: function() {
    if ((this.priceid + this.priceIterator) <= 50) {
      this.priceid += this.priceIterator;
    }
  },
  previousPrice: function() {
    if ((this.priceid - this.priceIterator) > 0) {
      this.priceid -= this.priceIterator;
    }
  }
};

event.nextPrice(); // 45
event.nextPrice(); // still 45
event.previousPrice(); //0
event.previousPrice(); //still 0
alert(event.priceid);
```

This solution uses object and context(this) to handle price. Also avoid in future making multiple functions with the same name inside conditions, that's very bad practice.

And to make it work for your angular app, just small change, instead of variable, use scope:

```
$scope.event = {
  priceid: 0,
  priceIterator: 45,
  nextPrice: function() {
    if ((this.priceid + this.priceIterator) <= 50) {
      this.priceid += this.priceIterator;
    }
  },
  previousPrice: function() {
    if ((this.priceid - this.priceIterator) > 0) {
      this.priceid -= this.priceIterator;
    }
  }
};
$scope.event.nextPrice();
$scope.event.previousPrice();
$scope.event.previousPrice();
alert($scope.event.priceid);
```